# Project Management methodology for small projects

Tags: project-management

there are a lot of articles/books etc about PM for medium or big projects. All articles which I found describes how to manage a project with at least few people involved.
In my case that is totally different, so this is my specific case:
I have a small team (4-6 developers) and we do small short-term projects. Usually one or sometimes two persons per project. Project's lifetime is about 1-2 month in general (but can be 6 months in case of customer related issues). All projects are  customer related, quite often there are some breaks in the projects because of lack documentation from customer or lack of hardware etc, so one person quite often handle 2-3 projects with different priorities at the time.

My question is: can any "popular" modern methodology be tailored to suite this types of tasks? What could you recommend (methodology/pm tools).
May be someone can give a link to an article about this type of software pm?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, any project management tool could be adapted to your team and you should first choose what type of project management methodology you want to follow. Personally i think Kanban could be a good fit as there are no specific deadlines or cut off for projects, just tasks. It also allows you to prioritize tasks and carry out several projects at once.

This is the methodology we use and we do have similar uncertainties when it comes to the length of the projects. The tool we have been using is [Eylean](http://www.eylean.com/kanban),  it allows us to follow the methodology and have the updated status of the tasks at all times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of Crystal Clear, which is Cockburn's method focused on smaller team work.  http://alistair.cockburn.us/Crystal+Clear+distilled

Answer (score 0):

Any methodology can be scaled, provided you don't fall for the dogma and consider it to be the "Best" or "Only" way, or that you need to follow all the principles completely.

That said, I'm a big fan of Extreme Programming myself.

However, in practice, on our projects, we "officially " use a Waterfall methodology, but within each phase our methods are more in line with Agile methodologies, and our official stance is that each PM will use whatever tools he or she needs, so long as the project is moving along, we are meeting our deadlines, and most importantly, the customer is getting what they need when they expect it.